# I am having trouble closing an <img> element and know WHERE the error is, but cannot correct it

Tags: xml, blogger

I am trying to edit a template for blogger and edited the code and uploaded it. I received an error code saying that an  element must be closed with ">" or "/>" which i know, however I closed the element and it still isn't validating. here is the code:

```
<div class='post-author'>
    <h4 class='block-heading'><span>About the Author</span></h4>
    <div class='author-img'>
        <img alt='' class='avatar avatar-110 photo' height='110' src='https://www.flickr.com/photos/34847437@N02/16125062891/ width='110'/>
    </div>
    <div class='author-text'>
        <h4><a href='' rel='author' title=''>Emilie Jay</a></h4>
        <p>UK Born, Pittsburgh raised, Kent educated- I am the girl-next-door who also likes to mix things up and experiment with the unexpected. I can be found in front of or behind a camera, creating art on canvas or on skin, and am excited to be sharing all of my experiences with you. Check back often, I am always working on something new!</p>
        <span class='author-share'>
            <a href='https://twitter.com/unfoundclovers'><i class='fa fa-twitter round-icon'/></a>                  
            <a href='http://instagram.com/unfoundclovers'><i class='fa fa-instagram round-icon'/></a>       

            <a href='http://www.pinterest.com/unfoundclovers/'><i class='fa fa-pinterest round-icon'/></a>                                  
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the error is appearing in the 4th line beginning with the  tag. It looks properly closed but like I said, isn't validating. Can anyone help?

Comment: Now you need a closing quote after the src attribute

Comment: You are missing a closing quote on your `src` attribute of the `img`. Look at the syntax colour hilighting

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I don't know how i missed that but you saved me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your src attribute is missing a closing quote

```
<img alt='' class='avatar avatar-110 photo' height='110' src='https://www.flickr.com/photos/34847437@N02/16125062891/' width='110'/>
```

See added `'` left of `width=` which is missing in your code.

Comment: can you elaborate? the src attribute is within the img attribute so I don't understand where a closing quote is missing